# How to store collection of value object in single field without creating new table in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I am using EF Core as my ORM, and I am learning Domain Driven Design.

As you may already know in DDD value object have no identifier and creating a separate table for value objects is not good practice.

But I want store a collection of value object without creating a new table, so how should I do that? Look at below example:

```
public class User : Entity 
{
      public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address : ValueObject 
{
     public string Country { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     // some other properties
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in a relational model, unless you serialize the data and stick it in a blob column. Otherwise, you _must_ have a table and you _must_ store one record per Address.

Comment: thanks .
but which one is better ? i think storing value object in Seprate table is not good,and serialization ? i think it is good way but i dont know ef core have any appropriate solution  for what i want(serializing a collection to single field)

Comment: It is completely subjective. Typically if you want to structure your data in this way, you use a non-relational database

Comment: [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations)

Comment: *"creating a separate table for value objects is not good practice"* DDD has nothing to do with how the data is stored in a relational database.

Comment: yes, but storing value object in seprate table means every record will have it's own identifier , but in DDD value object should not have any identifier.
I do not know much about  DDD but i think is not good practice and in every course that i watched they (instructors) try to avoid having seprate table

Comment: @sajad As others have mentioned, DDD isn't too concerned about persistence.  Having a separate table to store value object is quite normal.  You don't *have* to give a VO record an identifier, but I typically do.  The VO record would need to contain the related entity's Id though.  Just because the VO record has a DB identifier does not mean that it suddenly becomes an `Entity` since the domain model treats this as a Value Object.  A separate table is IMHO the easiest and most natural approach in a RDBMS world.

Comment: I second what @EbenRoux has said, also with efcore 6 you can make use of shadow properties so you aren't forced to have an ID in your value object class.

Answer (score 2):

so as alexander said , i decide to use value conversions(like below) :

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(user => user.Addresses)
            .HasConversion(
            a => (string)JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a),
            a => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Address>>(a));
        /*builder.HasData(Data.GetData<User>());*/
    }
}
```

and now a collection of address will store in single field

Comment: ... and now you cannot query database by address fields. you have to load all users from database and perform the query in memory. until json storage type is naturally supported by EF Core, this is *not* a good solution.

Comment: @IvanStoev saying "this is not a good solution" in not generically true, it depends on use cases.